# Replace every second comma in a text file

Tags: perl, shell, batch-file

I recorded some data on my laptop and because the OS system language is German it converted the decimal separator to a comma (didn't think of that at the time...).

The column separator (there are three columns in the text file) is a comma too and so I end up with six columns instead of three

Example.txt

```
4,0,5,0,6,0
```

should be

```
4.0, 5.0, 6.0
```

How can I loop through all files in a folder and replace every first, third and fifth comma with a point in all lines in my data-files? I would prefer a bash script (.sh) or possibly a perl solution

Comment: Why didn't the program generate proper CSV in the first place?

Comment: I will ask him, he is sitting next door :) Well, usually all our systems are english and a problem like this wasn't even thought of before. As this software is only used by a small group of people development is constantly going on. Or may be those things just happen if a physicist and a chemical engineer write software :)

Comment: as a physicist I resemble that remark! (http://everything2.com/title/I+resemble+that+remark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or how about awk

```
for F in * ; do awk -F,  'BEGIN { OFS = "," } ; { print $1"."$2, $3"."$4, $5"."$6 } ' $F | sponge $F ; done
```

You need "moreutils" for sponge, by the way. And back up your files first!

Comment: You should put the OFS definition in a BEGIN block. You don't need to do it on every line.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's always a two-way street posting on here :-)

Comment: Even though I did not ask for a awk solution, this one-liner did the job perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Generally for csv parsing you should use `Text::CSV`, however for this correction task, a quick and dirty could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $output;
#onen my $out, '>', 'outfile.dat'; 
#open my $in, '<', 'infile.dat';
#while(<$in>){
while(<DATA>){
  chomp;

  my @fields = split ',';
  while (@fields) {
    $output .= shift(@fields) . '.' . shift(@fields);
    $output .= ', ' if @fields;
  }

  $output .= "\n";

}

#print $out $output;
print $output;

__DATA__
4,0,5,0,6,0
4,0,5,0,6,0
```

of course you will read from a file rather than `DATA` and print to a new file presumably. I have added this real-world usage as comments.

Comment: can be shortened to `perl -F, -ane 'while (@F) {print shift(@F) . "." . shift(@F); print ", " if @F}'`

Comment: @glenn, thanks, I never have gotten the hang of the awk-like `-F`/`-a`/`@F`

Comment: further the `-i'.orig'` command line switch may be used to preserve the original with the `.orig` extension, just in case something should go wrong in the doing.

Comment: Good solution, I went with the awk script in the end as it uses sponge to override the existing file

Comment: @Martin H, anything that works is good, for future reference, the one-liner version (from glenn) with the `-i` switch I mention overrides the existing file too. With the `-i'.ext'` form it both replaces AND keeps a backup of the old file with the extension specified

Answer (score 1):

Well I see lots of valid and good answers here, here's another.

```
perl -wpe 'my $i; s/,/($i^=1) ? "." : ","/ge'
```

Here `/e` means "execute the replacement part"; `$i^=1` generates a 1,0,1,0...sequence, and `x?y:z` selects y or z based on x's value (i.e. `if (x) {y} else {z}`)

Answer (score 0):

Following perl script should help you.

```
 perl -e '$a = $ARGV[0]; $a =~ s/(\d)\,(\d\,)?/$1\.$2/g; print $a' "4,0,5,0,6,0"
```

OUTPUT

```
4.0,5.0,6.0
```

Comment: or `perl -pe 's/(\d+),(\d+,?)/$1.$2 /g'`

Comment: I agree with you \, is not required. My obsession with blackslashes need to be controlled :P

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, the necessary regex would be `s/,([^,]*,?)/.$1/g`.  If you apply this to a string, it will replace the first comma with a period, preserve the next comma (if any), and then start looking for commas again after the second one.